# Recursive variants and destruction on incomplete types

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to build an AST based on `std::variant` (I know there are other ways to do this, but I'm specifically interested in an approach around union types). I have two expression concepts

- LeafExpression
- RecursiveExpression

which I need in order to be able to use `std::variant` (because it doesn't allow recursive types). A leaf expression might look like this:

```
struct NameExpr
{
    std::string name;
};
```

and a recusrive expression like this:

```
struct CallExpr
{
    Expr target;
    std::vector<Expr> args;
};
```

`Expr` is the sum of all expression types:

```
struct BinaryExpr;
struct CallExpr;

using Expr = std::variant<
    Recursive<BinaryExpr>,
    Recursive<CallExpr>,
    ConstantExpr,
    NameExpr
>;
```

I have to forward declare my recursive expression types, because their definition requires a definition of `Expr`. `Recursive` is basically a `std::unique_ptr`. As I said, this class is only necessary to break the type cycle inside `Expr`.

My problem is that, like `std::unique_ptr`, my `Recursive` has a non-trivial destructor that deletes the the pointer to the actual expression. However, since I have to forward declare my recursive types, all types that use `Recursive` are incomplete at the time the template is instantiated, which in turn causes unintended (UB?) behavior in the destructor of that instantiation.

Can I solve this problem somehow or do I have to switch to a different design?

[(Somewhat) MRE](https://godbolt.org/z/r1f7n136v)

Comment: You need to show a [mcve].

Comment: `Recursive<X>` should be a complete type, whether or not `X` is complete.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. yes but my problem is `X` is incomplete: `Recursive<X>::~Recursive() { delete ptr; }`. That is a delete on an incomplete type, which is a problem, isn't it?

Comment: What about using a custom deleter there. Should be possible to give it the declaration of the deleter, without specifying the definition until later.

Comment: If you have `delete ptr` in a place where `ptr` points to an incomplete type, you don't get undefined behaviour, you get a compilation error. If you don't get an error, then it is not incomplete.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete): _If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion, and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undefined._

Comment: @super that could work, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Timo sorry you are right, but you will get a warning from any implementation.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. yeah, which is why I noticed this issue in the first place :D

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `~` and copy/move ctor and assign. Then default them after everything is defined.

You may also want to make `Expr` be a thin wrapper around variant, so you can forward declare it.

Comment: Kinda ugly to include a header at the bottom, ngl :D, but it actually works. I only pulled the dtor out, do I really have to pull ctor and assign as well? I'm getting no warnings / errors if I leave them inline.

Comment: Nvm just figured it out